# Loop Through a Workbook and Take a Value if Present in a Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA/Macros and have managed to get the `Worksheet` names into my `ActiveWorkbook`. I am now trying to check if a specific `Value` is present within a `Cell` and then put it in column B next to the `Worksheet` name I have already extracted.  Only specific sheets will have a value which is 1-54 as it is the address of an IED device and it is only the worksheets I care about.

Currently I am using this code to extract the `Worksheet` names so I can go on and use this a reference for extracting a range of information as i can't get the sheet number or sheet code name to reference properly.

```
 Sub GetSheetnames()
 'Turn off alerts
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  'Open the Workbook that i want to look for the worksheet names this 
  'white book template is a save as copy of another file as it makes it 
  'easier to reference as I work with 1000's of file with same format but 
   'are all saved as a different name

  Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Projects\ASE Templates\ASE Template White 
  Book.xlsx"
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab Names from white book")
  .Range("A:A").ClearContents
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  i = i + 1
 .Range("A" & i) = ws.Name

 Next ws

End With

 Workbooks("ASE Template White Book.xlsx").Close

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

What I would also like to add in is to check if the value in `H4` on each `Worksheet` is either present or not and if so to display the value in column B next to the extracted worksheet names that are in column A of my worksheet "Tab Names From White book"

I did look at rerunning the macro changing the

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab Names from white book")
   .Range("A:A").ClearContents
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       i = i + 1
      .Range("A" & i) = ws.Name
   Next ws
```

To

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab Names from white book")
    .Range("B:B").ClearContents
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       i = i + 1
       .Range("B" & i) = H4.value
```

Or

```
.Range("B" & i) = Cells(3,8).Value
```

This runs but doesn't do anything visible. Any help would be appreciated. Ideally I would like to run the macro once and fill out both columns at the same time

Comment: Try `.Range("B" & i) = ws.range("H4").value`. Without a sheet reference it will refer to the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as though you've not qualified the cell range you want to pick up, and `Set`ting the Workbook for easy reference later is also advisable.

```
Sub GetSheetnames()
'Turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the Workbook that i want to look for the worksheet names this
'white book template is a save as copy of another file as it makes it
'easier to reference as I work with 1000's of file with same format but
'are all saved as a different name

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Projects\ASE Templates\ASE Template White Book.xlsx")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab Names from white book")
    .Range("A:A").ClearContents
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        i = i + 1
        .Range("A" & i) = ws.Name
        .Range("B" & i) = ws.Cells(3, 8).Value
    Next ws
End With

wb.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```